# llOExcption thrown when reading a .bmp file in java

Tags: java, exception

I'm am trying to read a .bmp file called `circle1` that in is a package that has been imported to the class that contains the following method.

So far I have the following code, but when I run the following code I get:

> javax.imageio.llOException: Can't read input file!

```
public void setUp() throws IOException
{
    // minimumOverlapScore < synapsesPerSegment(not yet a field)

    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("circle1.bmp"));
    byte[][] greenInputData = new byte[30][40];

    for (int x = 0; x < inputData.length; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < inputData[x].length; y++)
        {
            int color = image.getRGB(x, y);
            //alpha[x][y] = (byte)(color>>24);
            //red[x][y] = (byte)(color>>16);
            greenInputData[x][y] = (byte)(color>>8);
            //blue[x][y] = (byte)(color);
        }
    }
    this.inputData = greenInputData;

    System.out.println(this.inputData);
}
```

Comment: is the bmp inside a jar, or is it a file on disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In straight SDK using [`Class.getResourceAsStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) is what you need instead of `File`.

If in Spring use `ResourceLocator.getResource("classpath:circle1.bmp")`;